# SystemVerilog concatenation assignment is incorrect

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was reading about concatenation from this [website](http://www.testbench.in/SV_19_OPERATORS_1.html). The `program` is as follows:

```
program main ;
bit [4:0] a;
reg b,c,d;
initial begin
b = 0;
c = 1;
d = 1;
a = {b,c,0,0,d};
{b,c,d} = 3'b111;
$display(" a %b b %b c %b d %b ",a,b,c,d);
end
endprogram
```

The result for this is:

`a 00001 b 1 c 1 d 1`

How is `c` getting the value of 0 in the result when assigned to `a` in concatenation, when it has been assigned as 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literals `0` and `1` are unsized, but they actually are implicitly 32-bits.  According to the 1800-2017 LRM, it's illegal to put an unsized numeric literal inside a concatenation because of this common mistake. The tool you are using is not catching this.

You should write this with explicitly sized literals

```
a = {b,c,1'b0,1'b0,d};
```

Answer (score 3):

In Verilog, if the bit width and base is not declared, it is assumed to be a 32-bit decimal. Therefore, `0` is synonymous with `32'd0`.

You want `a = {b,c,1'b0,1'b0,d};`. Or you could make it 2 bits of zero with with `a = {b,c,2'b0,d};`